# mdev: applet not found when trying to populate /dev on android

Tags: applications, linux, busybox

I'm trying to install Debian on the Android 4.4 (modded with cyanogenmod) that's installed on my nexus 10 to one external sd card. I'm reading this tutorial :

http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian

I've attached the Leef microSD microUSB Connector with a 64GB sd card inside to the mini usb port of my nexus 10 as you can see here :

[image: nexus 10 + leef connector]

The tutorial talks about the The ASUS Transformer TF101 and the instructions are based on this tablet. Instead I have a tablet nexus 10,that's equipped with an internal sd card where I have installed android 4.4 + cyanogenmod. For this reason I need to know how to change some part of the tutorial to adapt it to my situation. Anyway on my desktop computer I have partitioned the sd card in this way :

```
Disk /dev/sdf: 64.0 GB, 64021856256 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125042688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004504c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            2048    32767999    16382976    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sdf2        32768000   125042687    46137344   83  Linux
```

according with the tutorial,these are the commands that I have issued right now from my desktop pc to the tablet using the ssh connection :

```
mount -o rw,remount / ; 
mkdir /mnt/deb ; 
mount -t ext4 /dev/block/sda2 /mnt/deb ; 
mkdir /mnt/deb/proc ; 
mkdir /mnt/deb/sys ; 
mkdir /mnt/deb/dev ;
/system/xbin/busybox sh ;
~ # echo $$
2360
/system/xbin/busybox mount -t proc none /mnt/deb/proc ;
/system//xbin/busybox mount -t sysfs none /mnt/deb/sys ;
/system/xbin/busybox mount -t tmpfs none /mnt/deb/dev ;
/system/xbin/busybox mdev -s ;
mdev: applet not found
```

and now I'm freezed here. I've tried to find a solution by myself with google but I haven't found the solution. This is what I have tried to do :

```
~ # echo $PATH
/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin

~ # which busybox
/system/xbin/busybox

~ # find / -name mdev
/mdev

~ # cd /

~ # ln -s /system/xbin/busybox mdev

~ # /system/xbin/busybox mdev -s
mdev: applet not found
```

but where is the mistake ? thanks.

Comment: this is not a mistake. Your deployed busybox binary does not include mdev. What you need to do is: cross compile your own busybox for ARM with mdev included. Or look for a prebuilt ARM binary which includes mdev and replace the busybox binary which is currently installed.

Comment: According with the tutorial I have replaced the default busybox binary with the one that has been already compiled to support mdev. The error is gone,but I have not fixed the main problem that I have explained here : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97534/transfer-root-to-sdcard-with-switch-root-didnt-work ; infact the switch_root command still does not work. Can you help me further ? thanks.